# android activity won't show up

Tags: java, android, icons

I added an icon to menu. But after clicking the choice with the icon the exception pops up.

04-20 20:17:20.623: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {jusbrz.bakalauras/jusbrz.bakalauras.AllCourseUsers}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Activity was declared already. Was I suposed to add something to manifest after added icon?

Comment: Could you show the lines of the manifest where you declared this activity?

Comment: Post your whole manifest file, there may be a syntax or placement issue in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

activity needs to be declared in the manifest as

```
<activity android:name=".AllCourseUsers" />
```

Comment: if this isnt the main activity, then post the intent calling it and the manifest else post the manifest code here.

Comment: I checked one more time. The old declaration was missing. How it is possible?

Comment: i can't go away on its own. maybe some mistake you made while editing the manifest. does it work now?